# Python Dice Game error

Tags: python, dice

[Solved] It was a stupid typo. Sorry.

I'm currently learning python and I'm running into some errors, if you could point out how I could fix them and why they are errors that would be great as I learn through trial and error with projects like these.
The error;

```
Would you like one or two die?2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "diceRoller.py", line 34, in <module>
    rollDice2();
  File "diceRoller.py", line 18, in rollDice2
    result = random.randrage(2,13)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'randrage'
```

My code;

```
import random
import time

numDice = input("Would you like one or two die?")
if (numDice == 1):
    rollDice1();
else:
    rollDice2();

def rollDice1():
    result = random.randrange(1,7)
    print ("It landed on..")
    time.sleep(1)
    print(result)
    try:
        answer = input("would you like to play again? [y/n]")
    except:
        pass
    if answer in ('y','Y'):
        return True
    return False

def rollDice2():        
    result = random.randrange(2,13)
    print ("It landed on..")
    time.sleep(1)
    print(result)   
    try:
        answer= input("would you like to play again? [y/n]")
    except:
        pass
    if answer in ('y', 'Y'):
        return True
    return False

while rollDice1 or rollDice2():
    continue
```

Comment: That's a typo. It should be: `result = random.randrange(2,13)`

Comment: Thanks, I guess its time to go to bed, are both problems from that?

Comment: Also, I think you should define your methods earlier before calling them. And use a main method to test them.

Comment: @DamhanRichardson there is only one problem that you posted: 'AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'randrage''

Comment: You really need to learn to read a traceback, you will also have an issue with answer outside your try/except block and you must define before calling a function

Comment: Ah i didnt realise, so functions arn't able to be called unless they're defined above and not bellow?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yea I'm new to this and tend to struggle with interperting tracebacks unless they're very basic.. Any tips where I could learn it?

Comment: always pay attention to the very last line, it is usually pretty informative. You don't need the `try/except` where you are getting `answer` and if you are catching an exception, try catch the relevant one/ones

Comment: @PadraicCunningham That is there since I was going to try and create a try/except that would repeatedly ask them for a correct y/n value however I'm still learning exception handling

Comment: use a while loop if you want to take input

Comment: @PadraicCunningham If you have the time could you post a segment example of what it should look like? Thanks alot for your help anyway.

Comment: Ok I  will post a quick solution, will add comments tomorrow, time for sleep here

Comment: @PadraicCunningham You can leave the lot till tomorrow, Im on irish time so about to hit the hay anyway. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: On Irish time myself, I added an answer, I will explain the code tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def rollDice1():
    result = random.randrange(1,7)
    print ("It landed on..")
    time.sleep(1)
    print(result)

def rollDice2():
    result = random.randrange(2,13)
    print ("It landed on..")
    time.sleep(1)
    print(result)

def main():
    while True:
        numDice = input("Would you like one or two die?")
        if numDice ==  "1":
            rollDice1()
            break
        elif numDice == "2":
            rollDice2()
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid choice")
    while True:
        answer = input("would you like to play again? [y/n]").lower()
        if answer == "y":
            main()
        elif answer == "n":
           print ("Goodbye")
           break
        else:
            print("Invalid choice")
main()
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, The only thing i'd ask you to explain is your use of a main function, as I've said I'm still learning and I've never come across it before, does it work as any other function would? Also if I wanted could I add in;  if answer == "y" or "Y" to encounter if someone was using caps lock.

Comment: basically the main function just handles the input and calls the necessary functions based on the input, the while loops will keep looping until the user enters the correct data, when we call rollDice 1 or 2 we need to add a break after so we break out of the first loop after we get the result and ask the user if they would like to play again in the second

Comment: Never mind the question about could I change it to if "y" or "Y" i didnt see the .lower() That's a really clever idea!

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I was just wondering as a general thing in python does a main function differ to others?

Comment: No worries, the main function could be called anything. Python is not like some other languages where you need a main function. It could just as easily be called foobar